# ListView returns the same item after the first item choice

Tags: android, listview

I'm on my project and I have a problem with my ListView

Here is the code

```
public class shortstorymode extends ListActivity {

// Text read from file txt
String text = "";

String[] values = new String[] { "The Fox and The Crow", "The Giant and the traveller",
        "The Mongoose", "The Pet Shop", "The Wind and The Sun"};

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.rowshortstorylayout, R.id.labelshortstory, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

  }

 @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    //
    // I will read data from file text in assets folder here
    // to open what the text says, I have many text files to choose
    // based on the item the user clicked
   }
```

After I choose, for example, "The Fox and The Crow", it shows a layout with the data read from file "The Fox and The Crow.txt", then I return to choose another item, the layout shows the same text??? why?? someone help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the content of onListItemClick ?

Comment: Not to be a neat freak but your classes should start with capital letter, like ShortStoryMode, thats just "rule"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I must set: `"text = "";"` after display the text. Thank all of you for your replies

Answer (score 1):

change your code inside item click a little bit

```
    @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v,int position,long id) {
    String item = values[position];

   }
```

Comment: @Blackbelt then please add your answer so that the author will get his answer

Comment: @KarthikaPB you can't add an answer because the question is not complete, you don't see the stuff inside onListItemClick...

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position); is there he might be using this string to display the layout...read his question

Comment: @KarthikaPB, since you have added the answer could you plz explain what could be the problem in OP's code?

Comment: I am not sure it's with the recycling problem of listview as I havn't used simplelistview  for the purpose I am not sure if it can solve the problem please add your answer so that I too can get it

Comment: maybe it sounded a little bit rude. I didn't mean to be rude. My *that's completely wrong* , it was just to point out a bad practice (imho), and also getListAdapter().getItem(position); returns the same value as your values[position]

Comment: it's fine.but what do you meant by "that's completly wrong " comment I just want to get your answer that's all if this's a wrong answer I should delete the post that's why I'm asking ...

Comment: I deleted it, what I meant was, *it makes and difference in this case*, so your answer is not solving op's issue

Comment: ok fine then I'll delete it once I get a comment from the one who asked the question.

Comment: String item = values[position]; is just another way to get the item